# How to remove Three20 from the project

Tags: iphone, three20

Adding Three20 in your project has been made simple by the ttmodule.py script file. I was initially planning on using it in my project but i'm not, so i want to clean my project by getting rid of it. How can i remove it from my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look in the "Groups & Files" window and open the folder "Frameworks". There should be a lot of entries:

- Three20.bundle
- Three20Core.xcodeproj
- ...

Delete all of the three20 entries. After this clean your target ("Build -> Clean") and rebuild ("Build -> Build").

I hope this helps.

---

**EDIT:**

Two other ideas:

- Try to analyse the installation script (three20/src/scripts/ttmodule.py) to understand what changes the script has made
- Read the instructions for manual integration ("Adding Three20 to your project", https://github.com/facebook/three20) and revert all explained steps

Comment: That's easy enough, but when you use the script, it applied a lot of other changes to the properties etc. So, i was just wondering if there any way of deleting those along side these?

Answer (score 0):

This is really complex. ttmodule.py adds lot of entries in your pbxproj file. you can not remove all those lines manually, its not practical. There are hundreds of line added in pbxproj file and if you are modifying it manually by removing one line at a time, you will definitely end up making a mistake and corrupt it.

Also this is not the only problem we faced. If you have added the Three20 framework using ttmodule.py and have kept Three20 framework files outside your codebase as they suggest, then other developers also have to have the exact same structure on their mac. otherwise they will get build error for "not able to find three20" framework. If they try to add three20 again on their mac, then they will end up getting duplicate entries in pbxproj and header search path and will still get the same build error.

I would recommend to better include the three20 files along with your project code so that other developers working in your team does not have to worry about it but I can still not find a simple way to remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1. Open terminal
2. Write something like this according to your project:

   ~/Documents/mail: $ grep -lr "three20" *
3. You will see all files, that contain three20 string.
4. The main thing to make your project compile and start working is to delete three20 entries from project.xcworkspace file, that can be found in finder by right clicking your project file and selecting show package contents. Open this file in any editor(I use Fraise) and using find delete all entries. It is not hard to do this, I had about 3-4 entries there only.
5. Other user interface state files also may contain three20 entries, but they are not important.
6. Also you should delete anything else concerning three20 (files, folders, header search paths, etc.). It's more simple.